# Gene expression comaprison between sc RNA seq subgroups

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am comparing a set of 5 genes between two groups . For the Multiple hypothessis correction (BH test) do i need to correct for only 5 genes if i find two of them have p value less than 0.05 - do  i need to consider the total number of genes that are differentially expressed in those two groups or can i consider multiple hypothesis testing as 5 ?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated? Usually, single-cell RNAsequencing (sc-RNAseq) involves expression measurements of thousands of genes. If there aren't pre-specified hypotheses, all those genes would be included in the number for multiple-comparison correction. If you had _pre-specified_ hypotheses just about those 5 genes, before you got the sc-RNAseq data, then you would only need to include those 5. Please _edit the question_ to provide more details about how you chose those 5 genes; comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.